# Tab auto completion in jupyter lab not working inside functions like print

Tags: python, autocomplete, jupyter-lab

Tab completion works fine outside functions, for example:

[image: outside]

But, when I try the completion inside functions like print it doesn't work:

[image: inside]

These are the jupyter core packages I have installed:

[image: jupyter versions]

Comment: Do you have the most updated version of ipykernel?

Comment: Yes I had the ipykernel 6.23.1 (installed by default when running 'pip install jupyterlab') and maybe that was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that online in jupyter.org, it didn't work either. So I tried with cocalc online, and there it worked, so I run the following to see the version and I installed it in local and the auto completion worked as expected. So I think it was a version problem.

[image: Correct version]